# How to change a variable several times in VHDL?

Tags: variables, vhdl

I need to implement in code a such string below:

```
Q1 = (I1 & I2 & I3 | I3 & I4 & I5) & T2
```

**Q** — an output value, 
**I** —input values, 
**T2** — a timer

I did it using „after“, but I have to output a T2 value, so that’s mean that before „after” it was 0, after the “after” worked in 5 sec., I have to display the changes inside the time diagram (T2 should equal 1) 
How can I do that?

```
architecture logic_behavior of logic is
  constant T1 : time := 2000 ms;
  constant T2 : time := 5000 ms;
  constant T3 : time := 7000 ms;

  signal Q1_2: std_logic;

  signal Q4_I1: std_logic;
  signal Q4_I2: std_logic;
  signal Q4_I3: std_logic;

  signal TT2_I: std_logic := '0';   

begin
  Q1_2 <= (I1 and I2 and I3) or (I3 and I4 and I5) after T2;    

  Q1 <= Q1_2; --write direct output
  Q2 <= (not Q1_2); --write inverse output
  Q3 <= (not I1) or (not I2) or (not I3) or (not I4) after T3;

  Q4_I1 <= I1 after T1;
  Q4_I2 <= I2 after T2;
  Q4_I3 <= I3 after T3;
  Q4 <= Q4_I1 or Q4_I2 or Q4_I3;
end logic_behavior;
```

**Result:**
[image]

[logic.vhdl](https://pastebin.com/avjnuQms)

Comment: There is no variable in your design; only signals and constants ...

Comment: [Full code here](https://pastebin.com/avjnuQms)

Comment: Please embed your code. External links will be gone after some time ...

Comment: An additional link to logic.vhdl doesn't help. The language of your question isn't clear. Which targets of signal assignment statements are you trying to change? Which output signal(s) will that show up in? **T2** in your VHDL description is a constant of type TIME with a value of 5000 ms. Do you mean to use `TT2_I `in `Q1_2 <= (I1 and I2 and I3) or (I3 and I4 and I5) after T2;` (to match Q1 = (I1 & I2 & I3 | I3 & I4 & I5) & T2)? If that's the case how would TT2_I be calculated? Do you still want the T2 delay? You are confusing (at least some) of your readers.

Comment: ***How to change a variable several times in VHDL?*** Consider a signal instead of a variable. A signal *waveform* has a scheduling queue called a *projected output waveform* with one entry for any particular simulation time. A [testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiedF.jpg) capable of reproducing your waveform image shows how an assignment can assign projected output waveform elements. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.2 Simple signal assignments, 10.5.2.1 and 10.5.2.2 Executing a simple assignment statement. Waveforms with multiple elements do not synthesize.

Comment: The question is really hard to understand. To me, It is unclear what you want to achieve. Maybe you should ask with a much simpler example (with one or two signals) ?